# Can we create a wcf service for two protocols http and https

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-binding, wcf-ria-services, wcf-security

We need to create a WCF service which will be used by internal users using http and external users using https.
Is it possible to create WCF service for http and https protocols.

Comment: You will need two endpoints (one http, one https) to do so, but a given service can have multiple endpoints.  Plenty of examples on how to do multiple endpoints on MSDN and the web.

Comment: Tried like in the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556232(v=vs.110).aspx  but when the external user accessing the service using https protocol in the browser,svcutil.exe is pointing to http protocol instead of https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes we can do that by providing 2 endpoints.

1 end point with basic httpbinding

and the other endpoint with wsHttpBinding with bindingconfiguration specifies Transport security

Comment: Tried like in the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556232(v=vs.110).aspx  but when the external user accessing the service using https protocol in the browser,svcutil.exe is pointing to http protocol instead of https.